# Install Glassfish on linux server for JSP & Servlet compatibility

Tags: linux, jsp, servlets, glassfish, web-hosting

I am facing a issue that i had made a project in J2EE (JSP & servlet) and i had uploaded every file on web server.
My web server is linux server and so i need to `install glassfish server` on it.
And also i had stretched my hairs from many days but i am not successful in it.
Actually i am unaware that how can i install it.
If it happens then `JSP and servlet files will be compatible` and web server can read it perfectly.

Any kind of help is acceptable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glassfish is JSP & Servlet compatible by default :)

To install it, you have different options, depending on your operating system.

1)

Just unzip it manually.

- go to https://glassfish.java.net/download.html and download **glassfish-4.1.zip**
- setup Java (`JAVA_HOME` and `PATH`)
- use your favourite unzip tool or go to the folder with the zip file and type `unzip glassfish-4.1.zip -d /here/`
- type `/here/glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain` to start the server
- configure the server via `asadmin` or the Glassfish Admin UI

2)

For Glassfish 4.0 or 3.1 you can also use the installer package.

- go to https://glassfish.java.net/download-archive.html and download `glassfish-4.0-unix.sh`
- make sure that the file is executable (`+x`) before you run it
- follow the installer instructions